# Can a batch file have an if statements based of time measures?

Tags: batch-file

Im trying to make batch file that will simply spit random numbers (echo %random%) for a desired time (5 minutes) and then open a file and exit the batch.
It would look a bit like this:

```
@echo off                
color a    
title "random number machine"
cls

:talk  
echo  %random% %random% %random% %random%   
if [5 minutes has passed] (
start complete.vbs  
exit ) || (
goto talk )
```

Does anyone know if it is possible to do make such a timer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Practically it is possible to develop *any* process/task in a Batch file; however, if the problem is large, the Batch file also grows in complexity. In other words: it is difficult to write Batch files for large general applications, but relatively simple to write a Batch file for a certain specific small request.

The Batch file below can wait for a maximum of 59 minutes:

```
@echo off                
color a    
title "random number machine"
cls

set waitMins=5

rem Get MM:SS from current time, add the number of waiting minutes
rem and reassemble the final time in MM:SS format:

set /A "futureMM=(1%time:~3,2%-100+waitMins) %% 60 + 100"
set "futureMMSS=%futureMM:~1%%time:~5,3%"

:talk  
echo  %random% %random% %random% %random%
if "%time:~3,5%" neq "%futureMMSS%" goto talk

echo %waitMins% minutes has passed

start complete.vbs  
exit
```

The "complex" arithmetic calculation is required to eliminate left zeros from the number of minutes; otherwise, the `set /A` command issue an error ("invalid octal number") with `08` and `09` minutes. The final `+100` is a very simple way to insert a left zero when the result is less than 10.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible. You can parse the `%TIME%` environment variable. The script below is a bit rough, since it uses whole seconds only, but you could parse the 4th token too, which contains the microseconds, to get more precision.

```
@echo off
setlocal
color a
title "random number machine"
cls

:: Get starting time in seconds since midnight.
call :timestamp start

:talk
echo  %random% %random% %random% %random% 

:: Get current time in seconds since midnight.
call :timestamp now

:: Check for day wrap and correct if necessary
:: echo DEBUG: Timestamps = %now% and %start%
if %now% lss %start% set /a now=%now%+86400

:: Calculate difference in seconds
set /a diff=%now%-%start%
:: echo DEBUG: %diff% seconds have passed
if %diff% geq 5 (
  start complete.vbs  
  endlocal
  exit 
)

goto talk

:timestamp
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /f "tokens=1-3 delims=/:/ " %%a in ('echo %TIME%') do (
  :: Calculate the number of seconds since midnight, by multiplying the hour 
  :: and minute tokens with 3600 and 60 respectively.
  set /a timestamp=%%a * 3600 + %%b*60 + %%c
  :: echo DEBUG: %%a, %%b, %%c : !timestamp!
)
endlocal & set %~1=%timestamp%
goto :eof
```